# Auto refresh values in a group of <li> on a page after regular period of time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I have a set of `<li>` in my page as shown in here http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zzj7E/5/

Each `li` has 3 spans... one for comments, one for view and one for vote.

```
 <a class="example7" href="userpanel/comment.php?id=578" style="text-decoration:none; color:#666666; "><img src="content/comment/comments.png" width=18 height=18><i>No comments</i></a>
 <span style="text-decoration:none; color:none; margin:5px;"><img src="content/voting/eye.png" > 9</span> 
 <span class="vote"  id="578" name="up" style="text-decoration:none; color:none; margin:5px; "> <img src="/content/voting/yes-enb.png" width=12 height=12 alt=""> <span style="text-decoration:none; color:none">0 </span></span>
```

I want to autorefresh the values(count) in each of these elements every 2 mins. I know how to prepend/append divs but how to refresh selected elements in every `li` after a period of time?

This functionality is much similar to how Facebook autorefreshes the 'comment' count or 'like' count every time a user posts something.

Any ideas how I should go about it?

Comment: I know how to use the setInterval function. just not sure how to update only a particular <span> within every <li> :(((

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP is a server side scripting language, you cannot directly edit values that are already being displayed on the client computer. What you can do, however, is use AJAX to call a PHP script then parse the output into your spans (best method would be to JSON_encode your array on the PHP side then decode on the JS side..

```
function AJAX(){

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                      }
                    else
                      {// code for IE6, IE5
                      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                      }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                      {
                      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                        {

                        var data = xmlhttp.responseText;

                        var decoded = eval( "(" + data + ")" );

                        document.getElementById('span1').innerHTML = avayaevald['1'];
                        document.getElementById('span2').innerHTML = avayaevald['2'];
                        document.getElementById('span3').innerHTML = avayaevald['3'];


                        }
                      }

                    xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?loadAction=process",false);
                    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Then `setInterval(AJAX(), 120000);` and you'll be set.

Comment: Wooo!! sounds complicated. how diifcult is JSOn. I have heard of it but dont really know much about it

Comment: JSON is just a method of encoding an array/object into a string to pass between different systems. PHP has json_encode() json_decode() functions. Javascript can easily decode JSON with eval("(" + json_string + ")")  encoding is a little trickier. Take a look at http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php

Answer (score 2):

use JavaScript `setInterval` for timer.

Answer (score 0):

Like Chamika stated before, you'll need to use an interval, or timeout, either using
`setInteral('function', time_in_ms)` or

```
setTimeout('function', time_in_ms)
```

However, what you really want is an AJAX compoment, you'll need to use an HTTP Request, and make a page handler for the request (whichever platform you're using).

a good way is using jquery ajax `http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/`

Good luck.

Comment: `setTimeout` only execute one time and `setInteral` will execute periodically.

Comment: true, unless you have logic loop'd in your function aswell.

Answer (score 0):

This will run a function every 2 minutes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        alert("yo");
    },120000); 
});
```

As for the `ajax` part, which server are you using? PHP? JSF?

Comment: Thanks Ben. Am using PHP...actually i do know how to use the setInterval function, the real question is how to update only the particular values within the li. The 3 span values I showed in the question.